# Programmatically search multiple PDF files for keyword and note page number

Tags: search, pdf

I work for a museum with hundreds of scientific paper pdfs sitting in a directory. I have OCR'd all of them so that they can be searched for keywords in programs like Adobe Reader. I need to write a program that will allow me to search this directory for a specific species name and generate a list of the documents that match the keyword, and the corresponding page number.

I am looking for a pdf library that I can accomplish this task with that is (hopefully) free. I wrote a small program using the [PDFOne Library](http://www.gnostice.com/PDFOne_Java.asp) but the search took about 10 minutes to search for one term across the directory. I would like to cut the time down significantly as Adobe Reader and PDF-XchangeViewer can perform the same search in under a minute. I do not have a preference on language to use.

Can anyone direct me to the right resources so I may accomplish this task? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you evaluate the use of Apache Solr - which can index PDF files very efficiently.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/